# PAM: Master Password

Tags: ubuntu, security, pam, authentication

I want to create a master password that can log into any user account on a system without needing root privileges (but we can use root to create and set up the master password). In other words, I need to create a **backdoor** into PAM. I've already tried using [linx-pam-backdoor](https://github.com/zephrax/linux-pam-backdoor) and [pambd](https://github.com/ociredefz/pambd), but they are seriously outdated and no longer work. Therefore, I need to figure out a way to:

1. Develop a custom PAM module that authenticates users as long as they enter in the master password
2. Edit an existing PAM configuration file in `/etc/pam.d` to allow for this module to be used in accordance with the default user authentication module.

Is this possible? I know I can just `sudo su (user)`, but I'm making this for a cybersecurity challenge, where someone managed to create a backdoor right into a computer's authentication system that allows them to log into any user account, and they have to find out what the master password is, and remove the backdoor.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Comment: You can try using `pam_exec` to read the password: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39802243/2072269

Comment: `sudo su (user)` - you don't need both `sudo` and `su`

Comment: @roaima I only mentioned sudo because someone may think to answer "Just use sudo su; it's basically a built-in master password"... and if I used normal su, that's literally just logging into their account

Comment: @muru Yes, I think you're onto something! But how can I tell PAM whether the authentication is successful or not from the script itself?